# Debugging postgresql over pgadmin displays the wrong line

Tags: postgresql, debugging, postgresql-9.1, pgadmin

When debugging postgresql over pgadmin, the pgadmin debugger display always a line to low, i.e. if line 10 is going to be executed the marking will stay in line 11.

The problem is that the breaking points must also be set on a lower line, sometimes even on an empty or within a conditional that you know will not be executed, etc.

I doubt that is common... but I can't find anything on the web regarding this problem.
I'm on ubuntu 12.04, pgAdmin 1.14, server is pg 9.1

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the pgadmin I realized it's now in version 1.18.

Following the description in https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt upgrading was a no-brainer. And now it works as expected.